# iOS Apps that require a membership to use

Tags: ios, membership

I'm developing an iOS app for companies that will help them track their sales rep's progress throughout the day.  Tracks a lot of different info and helps with time management, etc.

The service requires that a company sign up for the service through the website.  Then they will have their sales reps download the app and sign in using their company account/login information.

So if a general user downloads the app, without first signing up for the service, the app won't work.

Is this a problem?  I can't find anything in the iOS documentation and Apple Developer Support is no help.

Does Apple require the the user be able to create an account within/through the app itself?  Do I need to provide some kind of content to someone who downloads the app but does NOT have a membership?  Like in the login screen?

Any input you might have would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds more like an enterprise app. If it goes to the store it would likely be rejected as normal users wouldn't be able to create an account I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are having a sales rep login with company info, I would imagine that when the app first launches, there will be a login screen. And most login screeens have hyperlinks like "Create an Account" and "Forgot Password?" That redirect users to a website in safari

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you described seems to violate Apple's terms of service. You should be fine and your app should be approved. But then again, Apple always has the final word.